# Efficient whole-screen animation with Javascript

Tags: javascript

My single-page app animates a whole 1920x1080 screen of photos constantly. Every pixel is moving all the time.

The memory footprint of this in Chrome keeps growing. Even when I use `requestAnimationFrame`, it grows past 1gb and beyond. I'm assuming it will grow indefinitely and crash the Chrome tab- or will it manage memory better at some point?

Is there any way I can improve the memory performance of this app? Perhaps by animating it less often / more slowly?

```js
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll_images);

    function scroll_images() {
        if (pos1 == frameheight * -1) { // If at the top of screen, move it to the bottom and populate it with new pics.
            pos1 = frameheight;
            populate(1);                // Populate the first frame with pics.
        } else {                        // Otherwise, keep moving up
            pos1--;
            elem1.style.top = pos1 + 'px';
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(scroll_images);
    }
```

Comment: You can use try using `css` `animation`, `transition`. Why do you call `requestAnimationFrame` twice?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's actually only called once, but it calls itself recursively.

Comment: It's really hard to find the problem using the provided code, can you put an example of what you're trying to do on jsFiddle?

Comment: @bevanb Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle of current implementation to demonstrate?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but I've updated the code to be more clear and concise. Basically, there's one 1980x1020 div on the page, with a bunch of pictures in it. Calling `scroll_images` makes it move up to the top (like swiping "up" on a smartphone). When it gets to the top, it is moved to the bottom again.